# nodemon: command not found -- on unix (mac)

Tags: node.js, macos, unix

I've tried every suggestion that I can find.  nodemon is definitely installed as a global module.  I've tried changing my path variable as well, but to no avail. I've attached an image of the terminal as evidence that it is a global module.  Help would be very much appreciated, thanks guys.  [Here you can see that it is in fact a global module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzTZw.png)

Comment: Did you use `npm install -g nodemon` to install it? Can you send the output of your PATH variable (`echo $PATH`)? Does it run if you `cd` into that folder and then execute `./nodemon`?

Comment: I just want to give a heads up, I had to completely uninstall homebrew and npm and delete any directories left behind by them.  Then reinstalled them and it seems to work fine now